# Problem 30 of GR8767 how is improper integral defined?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

In the subject test of 1987 problem 30 asks:

30. The improper integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) f'(x) \, dx$ is

A.) necessarily zero

B.) possibly zero but not necessarily

C.) necessarily nonexistent

D.) possibly nonexistent but not necessarily

E.) none of the above

**The accepted answer was (A.)**

My question, why is $\int_0^1 f(x) f'(x) dx = 1/2$ for $ f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ not a counter-example? I mean, $1/2 \neq 0$, this much is clear.

How should we think about this question? Is my integral not genuinely improper so it doesn't count?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you note that there is an instruction above problem 28 that gives information applying to problems 28 - 30?

The function is a semicircle with endpoints at $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ with $a<b$.

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE3.pdf

---

We want to show that $\int_a^b f(x)f'(x)dx=0$, with $f$ the semicircle described above.  This means $f(x)=\sqrt{(\frac{b-a}{2})^2-(x-\frac{a+b}{2})^2}$.

Then $f'(x)=\frac{-2(x-\frac{a+b}{2})}{2f(x)}$.

So $f(x)f'(x)=-x+\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Then $\int_a^b f(x)f'(x) dx=\int_a^b(-x+\frac{a+b}{2})dx=[-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{(a+b)x}{2}]_a^b=-\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}+\frac{(a+b)(b-a)}{2}=0$

Comment: ah ha. I did not notice that, this would help, although, it remains to show why it must be zero. I assume there is some easy method? Care to add that to your answer, I'd accept it then.

Comment: I had hoped there might be some slick countermeasure to direct calculation, but, on the other hand, it's not that bad. Thanks for your assistance, my student will appreciate it.

Comment: I think there is a way to do a substitution so that you are working with the upper unit semicircle.

Comment: @James S. Cook--I think I see the 'quick' way to do this problem: In general (for any nice-ish function $f$), $\int_a^b f(x)f'(x) dx=\left[\frac12 f(x)^2\right]_a^b=\frac12(f(b)^2-f(a)^2)$.  In the given problem, $f(a)=f(b)$, so the integral is $0$

Comment: Yes. That's the method intended. We can twist this problem many different directions in view of the above comment.